# Button click does not work in the entire copyright-infringing button image

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

First let me explain my structure, there is a background image which contains a button script, its used to know when the user clicked outside the button.

Here is it:
[image]

Then there is a button for each image, it is used to enable the button below it (the green one saying upgrade)

And finally the button that has problems:
[image]

During the game when I press this button it only works up till its half height, like the image below:
[image]

Just if there was no more button below that, firstly I thought it was because I have the background button and when I clicked below that it considered as the background, but when I deactivate the background button the same thing happens still.

Just for further reference, this is how it looks like during gameplay:
[image]

The button only shows when its image is clicked, when I click outside of its box I do GameObject.SetActive(false);

Since I actually think this has something to do with Unity UI I dont believe there is a need for any code, but if need just comment and I may publish (its a long code).

Comment: Besides your problem, pretty sure those images are not free to use.

Comment: I would say that there is a rectTransform blocking that part of the upgrade button. Can you please check and confirm if this is the case. Also are you sure that no other buttons are "eating up" the raycast when you click the bottom part of the upgrade. You may need to implement some Canvas Groups to deal with this.

Comment: According to the last two images the clickable part matches the size of that "X/Y" image. I think those two are somehow interfering.

Comment: @GunnarB. My bet is that the RectTransform of the images bellow the button in question is blocking it. Since they seem to be lower in the Canvas hierarchy and that means that they are on Top.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, just solved it and posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

couldn't be simpler, as well as your normal copyright-infrigement images,

you clearly have an extra "4000 (coins)" type of copyright-infrigement image that appears on the bottom.

you've stuffed something up on that image and the button - one is blocking the other or the like.

(Almost certainly you're resizing the "image but not the button" or something like that...but we are going to save you the boredom of dealing with that.)

Here is the solution

Re-engineer your images in any way you want, including changing them dynamically on the fly.

Then actually ***UNDER*** THE IMAGE have a button, make it expand all ways.  Totally STRIP the button - REMOVE both the image and text of the button.

Everything will now work perfectly - except empty buttons don't work. Since you can avoid all work by finding stuff on the internet, here it is below. It's a ***magic script you drop on empty buttons, and they then work***.

Important tips:

1) when you add your empty buttons, at first leave in a plain white 50% alpha image, so you can see where the buttons are.  Run your code which dynamically changes sizes / adds / deletes etc the images, and you can watch if the "transparent gray area" of the buttons stays correct.

2) dude you ***must use*** prefabs for buttons like this.  then you can change one and change them all at once.  make it a chance to learn how to use prefabs well

3) for all your copyright-infringement image units, now prefabs, you almost certainly must use Unity's (excellent) reactive layout system. you're going to have to learn about the horizontal and vertical layout groups.

remember, you simply ***can not*** produce non-reactive interfaces these days.

Again to recap. Unity's button system (while excellent) is very childish - they have the notion of an image "included on" the standard button, not to mention the ridiculous text element which comes underneath the standard button.

In practice you rarely work like that.  You have a "whole lot of stuff" (very likely dynamic, swapping images etc) and you want to, simply, "buttonize it" by dropping a button component ***on to*** that image stuff.

I have given you the solution below for transforming Unity's (excellent) Button, in to a grown-up, serious engineering "drop on" button. Enjoy!

```
/* Touchable.cs

So: basically use this to make invisible buttons.

Often it's much better to have your IMAGES
(any combination or layout you want),
as totally normal images.

Then, UNDER THE IMAGE, using four way stretching,
have a totally empty button (no image, no text).

This allows you to separate the image and buttons
functions.

You can then do absolutely anything you want to the
the images, eg, reahape, have multiple images, etc etc

There's only one problem with this, empty buttons
don't work.

In short, if you add this script to an empty button
- simply drop it on - the button then works perfectly.

Regarding precisely HOW this script works, I can't
be bothered explaining. Treat it as magic or search
long discussions about it on the www.
It's a little better engineering to go Touchable:Text
rather than building one from scratch with :Graphic,
since it will be more immune to Unity deprecations...
this is the correct solution for Touchable.cs.
*/

// Don't modify ONE CHARACTER in the code here!

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
[CustomEditor(typeof(Touchable))]
public class Touchable_Editor:Editor
    {
    public override void OnInspectorGUI ()
        {
        // just consider this magic and don't bother about it,
        // prevents treating component as a Text object in Editor
        }
    }
#endif

public class Touchable:Text
    {
    protected override void Awake()
        {
        base.Awake();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "He's not the hero StackOverflow deserves, but the one it needs right now..." :)

Comment: @JoeBlow Thank you for all the tips, it was really helpful, I'll consider using this option in future projects but this one is done and fixed with another way, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was a very stupid thing, the panel I used to make rows was made before I made the button, so when I created the button it simply was out of the boundaries, so when I clicked at the bottom part of the button it wouldn't work because it was not a click in the panel, I just solved it puttin every image some units up.
[image]